# When uploading a file through a fileupload, How can i get it to replace an existing file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am trying to create a page where you can download various resources, such as a PDF file. However I would like to be able to replace these PDF files with new ones as needed through a file upload. Here is my code so far for the download button.

```
protected void btnFocusDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=focus.pdf");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/resources/MumsZone.pdf"));
    Response.End();
}
```

And the code for the file upload which is in a separate `<form>`.

```
protected void btnFocusUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (uplFocus.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(uplFocus.FileName).Equals(".pdf"))
            {
                uplFocus.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("resources/focus.pdf"));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Issue uploading file');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to simply get it to replace the old file that was in the folder by giving it a new name but it didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `uplFamiliesFirst`?

Comment: uplFamiliesFirst was an error i've made as i was typing the code on this. it should read uplFocus and is the file upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FileUpload.SaveAs()` method has its own logic for what it does when it encounters a file with the same name in the location you want to save it.
Instead of replacing the file, it prefixes a number to the new filename to not overwrite the existing file.

The recommended solution to this is to save the `byte[]` array to a file instead.

This will overwrite the file if it already exists.

```
if (uplFocus.HasFile) {
   File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("resources/focus.pdf"), uplFocus.FileBytes);
}
```

Comment: This works now. Thank you so much silkfire. As you can probably tell I'm still learning a lot about this.